# What is the purpose of this line of code in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

I'm reading this [article](https://realpython.com/python-type-checking/#hello-types) and it has this example:

```
# game.py

import random

SUITS = "♠ ♡ ♢ ♣".split()
RANKS = "2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A".split()

def create_deck(shuffle=False):
    """Create a new deck of 52 cards"""
    deck = [(s, r) for r in RANKS for s in SUITS]
    if shuffle:
        random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck

def deal_hands(deck):
    """Deal the cards in the deck into four hands"""
    return (deck[0::4], deck[1::4], deck[2::4], deck[3::4])

def play():
    """Play a 4-player card game"""
    deck = create_deck(shuffle=True)
    names = "P1 P2 P3 P4".split()
    hands = {n: h for n, h in zip(names, deal_hands(deck))}

    for name, cards in hands.items():
        card_str = " ".join(f"{s}{r}" for (s, r) in cards)
        print(f"{name}: {card_str}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    play()
```

Please help me explain the line: 
`hands = {n: h for n, h in zip(names, deal_hands(deck))}`

What is this doing? @@ I have no idea with the syntax {n: h for n, h in ...}

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It creates a Dictionary with the player hands.
It is equivalent with:

```py
hands = {}
for name, hand in zip(names, deal_hands(deck)):
   hands[name] = hand
```